# limit value for user

Tags: java, object

My question is how can I limit the value use enter for a variable 
example :

```
public void nitro(int x) {
    /*if (x < 0) {
        break;
    }*/
    speed += x;

}
```

I know that break working on a loop only
thanks

Comment: `return;` to stop execution and return back to caller?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to already know, using `break` inside a loop causes the code inside that loop to terminate.  The conceptually similar concept to terminate code in a method is to use `return`, e.g.

```
public void nitro(int x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return;
    }
    speed += x;
}
```

Comment: return will abort the execution to speed? because that what I need 10x

Comment: No, `return` will cause the method to terminate and return to the caller.